# Change in actionbar on opening in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have changed actionbar color and other things to open in required color and text but when I open the app: The app opens with default theme and immediately changes to given theme.

This happens in phones like Galaxy Nexus, Nexus 4 but not on Nexus 5. I am not sure why this is happening?

I have set the actionbar before setContentView in my APP

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.actionBarColor)));
    
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
```

I got the theme using: http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

My style which I got from the above looks like this:

```
<style name="Theme.link" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/ThemeFor.OverFlow</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_link</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.link</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.link</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.link</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.link</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.link</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_link</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_link</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.link</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.link" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_background_textured</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_link</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_background_textured_link</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.link</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.link" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_transparent_link</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.link</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.link" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_link</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView.link" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_link</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.link" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_link</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav.link" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_link</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_link</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_link</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBar.link" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_link</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.link" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_link</item>
</style>

<!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
<style name="Theme.link.Widget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.link</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.link</item>
</style>
```

And I am calling the theme in Manifest:

```
   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.link" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Link_Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Link_Support"
        android:label="@string/action_support"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.ylg.linking.Link_Main" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Can somebody help me fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Set the icon and background color of action bar using styles.xml only. You are doing it programmatically in onCreate() causing this problem. @TheDevMan

Comment: @Pooja: How do i add the both to styles.xml?

Comment: I posted answer please check it and let me know. @TheDevMan

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.link</item>` to your base Activity style in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Can you please explain what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change a value for `android:background` in `ActionBar.Solid.link` to `@color/actionBarColor`.

Comment: The only change I can think of is to apply `Theme.link` directly to `Link_Main` activity. And how does the loading screen look like when the theme is not applied. Can you attach a screenshot please?

Comment: I am unable get the screen shot... The actionbar changes immediately.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when the application run, it gets style from styles.xml so your default style would be visible to you and after that you are changing actiob bar in onCreate() so theme changes immediately. To solve this set the icon and background color of action bar using styles.xml only using below code.
Try it. Hope it works.

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
      ..... 

     <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar"  arent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/actionBarColor</item>
    <item name="android:text">""</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

And remove below code.

```
getActionBar().setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.actionBarColor)));
```